# SSIS package fails intermittently with: Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server, version=11.0.0.0

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

I have an SSIS package deployed to the SSIS catalog on my Data warehouse which has run successfully for months. The package is executed by a SQL agent job.

Now it fails intermittently with the following error:

SQL agent history says says:

> Date      6/12/2015 6:00:00 a.m. Log      Job History (PBI) Step ID       1
>   Server        DEV-DW Job Name     PBI Step Name       Customer DETL
>   Duration      00:00:12 Sql Severity   16 Sql Message ID   27195 Operator
>   Emailed    Operator Net sent   Operator Paged  Retries Attempted  0
>   Message Executed as user: \. The operation failed
>   because the execution timed out. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 27195).  The
>   step failed.

In the SQL logs it says:

> Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server,
>   version=11.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=xxxxxxxxxxxx,
>   processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 73
>   (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].103).

1. Why would it only fail sometimes?
2. Why is it failing now?
3. What is the root cause?
4. How can I fix this?

Running SQL 2012 SP2 (11.0.5343) on Win 2008 R2 Standard SP1 on VMWare.

Edit: Updated to SQL 2012 SP3 (11.0.6020).

Edit: have added more context and clarified.

Following suggestion from @TheGameisWar, I queried ssisdb

SELECT *
FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[event_messages]
WHERE event_name = 'OnError'

Returns no error messages for that date.

Comment: What else has happened on the box besides patching from SP2 to SP3? Failover in a cluster? New DBA/team administering the box? Virus scanner installed/turned on?

Comment: No other changes. The few cryptic responses i found when searching for the error referred to hotfixes and CU's even though they seem vaguely related. I thought I should ensure I was on current version before pleading for help. (even if there was low probability the update resolves the issue). Task is scheduled to run overnight will confirm tomorrow if it has resolved issue.

Comment: I think I remember seeing this after someone's done a restore of the SSISDB poorly, or they've changed user/owner, etc. Patches rarely hurt though so won't knock you on that point

Comment: Task owner should be sa. Will confirm tomorrow. But that shouldn't have changed over the weekend when it occurred last.

Comment: That is not the error,unloading an (assembly in sql is loaded outside buffer pool memory as  clr component) is due to memory pressure,you can query the exact error by querying ssisdb.catalog.event_messages where event_name=onerror'

Comment: Have clarified error in original text. Agent history says timeout. SQL log  says unsafe assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now run successfully for ~1.5 weeks. The more I think about it I believe that the ssis error (posted in title) was a side effect, and was the result of the timeout caused by the dataload connection.

I can't prove or disprove if installing SP3 had any effect at all.

In my opinion the comment from @TheGameiswar is the best indicator pointing to root cause.